# выдает ошибку в на Js

Tags: javascript

```
<script language="javascript">
var exitsplashmessage = '10000';
var exitsplashpage = '';

function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function () {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}

function addClickEvent(a, i, func) {
  if (typeof a[i].onclick != 'function') {
    a[i].onclick = func;
  }
}

var theDiv = '<div id="ExitSplashDiv" style="display:block; width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; background:#FFFFFF; margin-top:0px; margin-left:0px;" align="center">';
theDiv = theDiv + '<iframe src="' + exitsplashpage + '" width="100%" height="100%" align="middle" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
theDiv = theDiv + '</div>';
theBody = document.body;
if (!theBody) {
  theBody = document.getElementById("body");
  if (!theBody) {
    theBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  }
}
var PreventExitSplash = false;

function DisplayExitSplash() {
  if (PreventExitSplash == false) {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    PreventExitSplash = true;
    divtag = document.createElement("div");
    divtag.setAttribute("id", "ExitSplashMainOuterLayer");
    divtag.style.position = "absolute";
    divtag.style.width = "100%";
    divtag.style.height = "100%";
    divtag.style.zIndex = "99";
    divtag.style.left = "0px";
    divtag.style.top = "0px";
    divtag.innerHTML = theDiv;
    theBody.innerHTML = "";
    theBody.topMargin = "0px";
    theBody.rightMargin = "0px";
    theBody.bottomMargin = "0px";
    theBody.leftMargin = "0px";
    theBody.style.overflow = "hidden";
    theBody.appendChild(divtag);
    return exitsplashmessage;
  }
}

var a = document.getElementsByTagName('A');
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  if (a[i].target !== '_blank') {
    addClickEvent(a, i, function () {
      PreventExitSplash = true;
    });
  } else {
    addClickEvent(a, i, function () {
      PreventExitSplash = false;
    });
  }
}
disablelinksfunc = function () {
  var a = document.getElementsByTagName('A');
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].target !== '_blank') {
      addClickEvent(a, i, function () {
        PreventExitSplash = true;
      });
    } else {
      addClickEvent(a, i, function () {
        PreventExitSplash = false;
      });
    }
  }
}
addLoadEvent(disablelinksfunc);
disableformsfunc = function () {
  var f = document.getElementsByTagName('FORM');
  for (var i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
    if (!f[i].onclick) {
      f[i].onclick = function () {
        PreventExitSplash = true;
      }
    } else if (!f[i].onsubmit) {
      f[i].onsubmit = function () {
        PreventExitSplash = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
free - litecoin.com(10000);
window.onbeforeunload = DisplayExitSplash;
</script>
```

при запуске выдает ошибку:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

указывая на первую строчку

Comment: Вы всегда функции в одну строку пишите?

Comment: Я понимаю что вопрос не в тему, но я хотел разобраться в вашем коде, и теперь у меня глаза болят.

Comment: Мой хрустальный шар в ремонте, но что-то мне подсказывает что вы это пишите в JS-файле. В нём не нужны теги.

Comment: А это что если не секрет `free-litecoin.com(10000);`?

Answer (score 1):

В файле JS  теги `<script language="javascript">` и `</script>` не нужны. Вот если бы JS код писали в файле html, то нужно было бы

Comment: еще на строку free - litecoin.com(10000); выдает ошибку Uncaught ReferenceError: free is not defined
    at <anonymous>:14:1

Comment: А нечего бездумно копировать код с сайта...

Comment: а решить проблему то как

Comment: Немного подумать и понять что это и зачем нужно

Comment: а вы не поможете?

Comment: Ну а вы сами подумайте. На ваш взгляд что это за строка и что делает?

Comment: ну что трудно человеку сразу помочь?

Comment: Подсказка: "На ваш взгляд что это за строка и что делает?"

Comment: вы скажите,как правильно написать или нет?

Comment: Правильно написать - это надо так, чтобы это удовлетворяло правилам написания кода на JS и чтобы выполняло корректно ту задачу, которая поставлена для этого кода